# How to hide/show a uiview when uiscrollview Y position changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a uiview in my app. I want to show the uiview when uiscrollview Y position changes. I tried some stackoverflow suggestion but can't get the expected result.
Here's my code that i tried:

```
if (topScrollView.contentOffset.y) >= 30{
   slideInSearchView.isHidden = false
} else {
   slideInSearchView.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure code is inside `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (topScrollView.contentOffset.y) >= 30{
        slideInSearchView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        slideInSearchView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set delegate of the scrollView ?

Comment: can you reverse the assigning - isHidden - in both statements above

Comment: still nothing is happening

Comment: added a break point inside the function ??

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i put the code inside viewdidload before, so silly of me, thank you